reduce the json file size from larger mb to very small mb in evidentlyAI
i need to aggregate the json file which contains model explainability(xai metrics , alibi library) , so that i can reduce the size of json file eg. from 200 mb j to 2 mb json file, is it possible to reduce size file in evidently ai, the file contains only metrics and that for ml monitoring purpose and also i dont need to zip the file, for unzipping it may take long time, we give our json files to cloud and our backend team will fetch that so at that time we want to fetch the files more quickly to display in UI. is there any way to sort out this ?
i need to reduce the size of json file so that fetching time will also reduce,  is there any possible ways doing this in evidently AI ?
